# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required while installing Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

While trying to install Pandas and sasl modules in Windows via pip, I am getting below error.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

I have tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 but getting the same error. My Python version is 3.4.0 and pip version is 18.1

```
C:\Users\ishan\PycharmProjects\python-Simple\venv\Scripts>python --version
Python 3.4.0

C:\Users\ishan\PycharmProjects\python-Simple\venv\Scripts>pip --version
pip 18.1 from c:\users\ishan\pycharmprojects\python-simple\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pip (python 3.4)
```

Comment: It may be sound as silly but have you tried a reboot? (actually a logout/login is more than enough, but I think you are missing a refresh of the env variables)

Comment: yes, I tried the same. Getting again the same error.
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ds42qyvg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\ishan\PycharmProjects\python-Simple\venv\include\site\python3.4\pandas" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pandas\

Comment: If you check in start for "visual studio", do you have a "Command prompt for Visual Studio"? (or something on the same line)